# .BAT file glitch minecraft effect genorator

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7, command

I have this code that is

```
    @echo off
    color a
    title Minecraft Effect Generator
    mode con: cols=114 lines=40
    :1
    cls
    echo -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    echo                                            Minecraft Effect Generator
    echo -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    echo /effect "USERNAME" "EFFECT ID" "TIME LASTS" "LEVEL"
    echo [ E  ] EXIT           - EXIT THE MINECRAFT EFFECT GENERATOR
    set /p "MCUsername=Username: "
    IF MCUsername==e exit
    IF MCUsername==E exit
    :2
    cls
    echo -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    echo                                            Minecraft Effect Generator
    echo -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    echo /effect %MCUsername% "EFFECT" "TIME" "LEVEL"
    echo [ 1  ] SPEED           - RUN FASTER  BY 20% EACH LEVEL
    echo [ 2  ] SLOWNESS        - RUN SLOWER  BY 15% EACH LEVEL
    echo [ 3  ] HASTE           - MINE FASTER BY 20% EACH LEVEL
    echo [ 4  ] MINING FATIGUE  - MINE SLOWER BY 20% EACH LEVEL
    echo [ 5  ] STRENGTH        - HIT HARDER  BY 130% EACH LEVEL
    echo [ 6  ] INSTANT HEALTH  - PLAYER GETS 4 ()() HEALTH . UNDEAD MOBS TAKE 6 ()()() DAMAGE -- DOUBLES BY EACH LEVEL
    echo [ 7  ] INSTANT DAMAGE  - PLAYER TAKES 6 ()()() HEALTH . UNDEAD MOBS TAKE 6 ()()() DAMAGE -- DOUBLES BY EACH LEVEL
    echo [ 8  ] JUMP BOOST      - JUMP HIGHER 1/2 BLOCK . REDUCES FALL DAMAGE BY 1 ( DAMAGE ON LEVEL 1 
    echo [ 9  ] NAUSEA          - WOBBLES AND WARPS THE SCREEN . LEVEL DOES NOT EFFECT THIS EFFECT
    echo [ 10 ] REGENERATION    - REGENERATE 1 HEART ( PER 50 TICKS . EACH LEVEL CUTS THE TIME IN HALF (ROUNDED)
    echo [ 11 ] RESISTANCE      - RESIST BY 20% EACH LEVEL
    echo [ 12 ] FIRE RESISTANCE - IMMUNITY
    echo [ 13 ] WATER BREATHING - PREVENTS AIR BAR FROM DECREASING WHILE UNDERWATER . SLIGHTLY INCREASES SIGHT UNDER WATER
    echo [ 14 ] INVISIBLILTY    - MAKES PLAYER DISAPPEAR . MOBS WILL NOT ATTACK PLAYER / MOB UNLESS TOUCHED
    echo [ 15 ] BLINDNESS       - PLAYER SEES BLACK FOG . PREVENTS SPRINTING AND CRITICAL HITS . LEVEL DOES NOT EFFECT
    echo [ 16 ] NIGHT VISION    - INCREASES LIGHT LEVEL TO PLAYER TO 15 EVERYWHERE . DOES NOT AFFECT OTHER PLAYERS / MOBS
    echo [ 17 ] HUNGER          - ADDS 0.025 FOOD EXHAUSTION PER TICK EACH LEVEL
    echo [ 18 ] WEAKNESS        - MINUS 0.5 DAMAGE DEALT EACH LEVEL
    echo [ 19 ] POISON          - DEALS 1 ( DAMAGE EVERY 25 TICKS UNTIL PLAYER HAS 1 HEART LEFT . EA LV CUTS TIME IN HALF
    echo [ 20 ] WITHER          - DEALS 1 ( DAMAGE EVERY 40 TICKS AND CAN KILL PLAYERS / MOBS . EA LV CUTS TIME IN HALF
    echo [ 21 ] HEALTH BOOST    - ADDS 4 ()() BASE HEALTH PER LEVEL AND VANISHES WHEN EFFECT ENDS
    echo [ 22 ] ABSORBATION     - ADDS 4 ()() NON REGENERATEABLE HEALTH PER LEVEL AND VANISHES WHEN EFFECT ENDS
    echo [ 23 ] SATURATION      - REGENERATES 1 FOOD PER LEVEL
    echo [ E  ] EXIT           - EXIT THE MINECRAFT EFFECT GENERATOR
    set /p "effect=Effect ID: "
    IF effect==e exit
    IF effect==E exit
    :3
    cls
    echo ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    echo                                            Minecraft Effect Generator
    echo ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    echo /effect %MCUsername% %effect% "TIME" "LEVEL"
    echo [ U  ] UNLIMITED TIME - NEVER-ENDING EFFECT
    echo.
    echo [ E  ] EXIT           - EXIT THE MINECRAFT EFFECT GENERATOR
    set /p "time=Time: "
    IF time==e exit
    IF time==E exit
    IF time==u set /a "time=100000"
    IF time==U set /a "time=100000"
    :3
    cls
    echo ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    echo                                            Minecraft Effect Generator
    echo ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    echo /effect %MCUsername% %effect% %time% "LEVEL"
    echo LEVEL IS 1 - 255
    echo [ E  ] EXIT           - EXIT THE MINECRAFT EFFECT GENERATOR
    set /p "level=Time: "
    IF level==e exit
    IF level==E exit
    :end
    cls
    echo ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    echo                                            Minecraft Effect Generator
    echo ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    echo YOUR COMMAND IS:
    echo /effect %MCUsername% %effect% %time% %level%
    echo TYPE THIS INTO YOUR CHAT TO WORK
    echo [ C  ] COPY TO CLIPBOARD
    echo [ B  ] GO BACK AND TRY AGAIN
    echo.
    echo [ E  ] EXIT
    set /p "end=>"
    IF end==e exit
    IF end==E exit
    IF end==c echo /effect %MCUsername% %effect% %time% %level%| clip $goto end
    IF end==C echo /effect %MCUsername% %effect% %time% %level%| clip &goto end
    IF end==b goto 1
    IF end==B goto 1
    goto end
```

Basicly it generates a command. It seems to glitch at `:end`. The input seems to not work. How can i fix this?  Is my computer not working or is it the code that is glitched???
BTW: I am running Windows 7 x64
Thanks for reading this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many, many errors.

First obvious one is that you have two labels `:3` but that's nothing to do with the problem you raised.

```
IF end==e exit
IF end==E exit
```

`end` can never equal `e`. You need the **contents** of `end` which is `%end%` - similar problem repeated throughout the code.

The `if` statement allows the `/i` switch to make the comparison case-insensitive.

```
IF /i "%end%"=="e" exit
```

will suffice. Note the arguments are "quoted". This affords some protection against certain input characters (since the input is uncensored by `cmd`) which may cause `cmd` to have problems - an input such as `hello there` for instance. This scheme **improves** the input-handing, but it is **not** bullet-proof.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I have not programmed in 1 year so I have problems. XD  :D

Comment: OMG I just noticed i spelled generator wrong! I spelled it "genorator" instead of generator. --PALM SLAP--